# UIImage from image picker blurry

Tags: iphone, ios, uiimage

I know this question has been asked quite a few times but can't figure out why my UIImage is still blurry.

What I've done:

- Import image from UIImagePicker.
- Resized image according to the code here: http://vocaro.com/trevor/blog/2009/10/12/resize-a-uiimage-the-right-way/
- Initialised a UIImage with initWithImage to hold the UIImage. Added this as a subview, made the frame CGRectIntegral(frame) to ensure all frame's coordinates are integers.

Despite this, the UIImage that appears on screen is still a bit blurry. Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Code:

```
UIImage *gotImage = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];

float scale = (self.view.frame.size.width)/(imageToResize.size.width);
imageToResize = [imageToResize resizedImage:CGSizeMake(scale * imageToResize.size.width, scale * imageToResize.size.height) interpolationQuality:kCGInterpolationHigh];

UIImageView *background = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:imageToResize];
background.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
background.frame = CGRectIntegral(background.frame);
[self.view addSubview:background];
```

Comment: Are you seeing this problem on retina devices?

Comment: Further to Jeff's question, does `scale = (self.view.frame.size.width*self.view. contentScaleFactor)/(imageToResize.size.width)` solve the problem?

Comment: Yes, I'm seeing this on a retina device - tried adding contentScaleFactor to the scale but didn't seem to make a difference unfortunately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to figure it out - I added two lines:

```
UIImage *gotImage = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];

float scale = (self.view.frame.size.width * [[UIScreen mainScreen] scale] )/imageToResize.size.width; //Changed line
imageToResize = [imageToResize resizedImage:CGSizeMake(scale * imageToResize.size.width, scale * imageToResize.size.height) interpolationQuality:kCGInterpolationHigh];

UIImage *testImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:blurredImage.CGImage scale:[[UIScreen mainScreen] scale] orientation:blurredImage.imageOrientation]; //Changed line
UIImageView *background = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:testImage]; 

background.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
background.frame = CGRectIntegral(background.frame);
[self.view addSubview:background];
```

Answer (score 0):

You might attempt to set rasterization on the UIImageView layer.

Reason being, you're picking the Original image, which depending on the device can be 1000s of pixels. Then your squishing it down using aspect fit. There is no rasterization to smooth out the image.

Thats my guess. Without device info your question is kind of tough to answer.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion - tried adding this on but didn't seem to make a difference. Testing on an iPhone 5.